# Codable Enum with arguments and _ fails at compile time

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I've noticed that I'm receiving compile time errors for a very certain enum type.  It can be reproduced with the following:

```
enum ThisEnumCompiles {
    case stringArgument(_ string: String)
    case intArgument(_ int: Int)
}

enum ThisEnumAlsoCompiles: Codable {
    case stringArgument(string: String)
    case intArgument(int: Int)
}

enum ThisEnumDoesNot: Codable {
    case stringArgument(_ string: String)
    case intArgument(_ int: Int)
}
```

No errors for the last enum are showin in XCode until you actually build when you'll get:

```
<unknown>:0: error: type 'ThisEnumDoesNot' has no member 'stringArgument(string:)'
<unknown>:0: error: type 'ThisEnumDoesNot' has no member 'intArgument(int:)'
```

It is unclear to me why adding the `_` makes the last enum un-compilable whereas it is fine if it has not conformed to `Codable`

Comment: You need a custom encoder like: https://pastebin.com/55XrCnM7

Answer (score 0):

You might want to adopt a specific `Codable` strategy for those kind of `enum`.

Here's an example:

```
enum MyEnum {
    case opt1(String)
    case opt2(Int)

}

extension MyEnum: Codable {
    private enum _Base: String, Codable {
         case option1
         case option2
     }

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case base
        case opt1Value
        case opt2Value
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let b = try container.decode(_Base.self, forKey: .base)
        switch b {
        case .option1:
            let v = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .opt1Value)
            self = .opt1(v)
        case .option2:
            let v = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .opt2Value)
            self = .opt2(v)
        }
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        switch self {
        case .opt1(let v):
            try container.encode(_Base.option1, forKey: .base)
            try container.encode(v, forKey: .opt1Value)
        case .opt2(let v):
            try container.encode(_Base.option2, forKey: .base)
            try container.encode(v, forKey: .opt2Value)
        }
    }
    
}
```

What do I do here? I use a nested `_Base` enum which is `Codable` by default (its raw value is always a string) and that will represent in the data representation the *"base case"* of the enum to encode/decode.
I then use different coding keys for each kind of value associable to each *"base case"* of the enum to represent.
The compiler is gonna be your friend later on if you eventually decide to change your enum and add/remove cases to it for the Codable implementation.

**EDIT**

Your question specifically refers to automatic `Codable` synthesizing for `enum` with associated values in Swift version 5.5 (prior that we had to write it as I did here).
Well in this case when you add a label for the associated value, that’ll be used as coding key in the `Codable` automatic synthesize conformance, on the other hand if you don’t a `_0`, `_1`… series is used as coding keys.
Therefore doing:

```
enum MyEnum: Codable {
    case opt1(_ string: String)
}
```

most likely adds confusion and the compiler can’t chose which one between `”_0”` and `”string”` values it should use as `CodingKeys` values.

Comment: `
enum MyEnum {
    case opt1(string: String)
    case opt2(int: Int)
}
`
Achieves the same without all the boilerplate, no?

Comment: As I've already mentioned in my answer this approach will also strengthen your code at compile time in future in case you'll need to add/remove cases to the enum.

Comment: Adding or removing cases without the boilerplate would throw on any switch statements as it is.  Regardless, this doesn't answer the question why simply adding a `_` changes behavior.

Comment: Probably cause implicitly labeling those associated types, coding keys cannot be automatically synthesized.

Comment: One more thing: maybe you’d better tag this question as specific for Swift 5.5 (or state it somewhere that some of those examples would only compile adopting Swift 5.5) cause **automatic Codable synthesizing for enum with associated values was added in Swift 5.5**.

Comment: Will do and thank you for the edit, that makes sense.  The reason for the question is we're specifically moving away from all the Codable implementation in your answer which we already had.  With Swift5.5 we found it strange we had to move to things like `.caseForString(string: String)` rather than `.caseForString(_ string: String)`